# converting dict into a dataframe?

Tags: python

```
{'student1': 45,
 'student2': 78,
 'student3': 12,
 'student4': 14,
 'student5': 48,
 'student6': 43,
 'student7': 47,
 'student8': 98,
 'student9': 35,
 'student10': 80}
```

How to convert this dict into a dataframe

Comment: pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns', dtype=None, columns=None) → 'DataFrame'

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

student = {
    "student1": 45,
    "student2": 78,
    "student3": 12,
    "student4": 14,
    "student5": 48,
    "student6": 43,
    "student7": 47,
    "student8": 98,
    "student9": 35,
    "student10": 80,
}

df = pd.DataFrame(student.items(), columns=["name", "score"])
print(df)
```

```
        name  score
0   student1     45
1   student2     78
2   student3     12
3   student4     14
4   student5     48
5   student6     43
6   student7     47
7   student8     98
8   student9     35
9  student10     80
```

Comment: and if you want to use name as index, do `df.set_index("name")`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd 

# intialise data of lists. where each key will be your column 
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]} 

# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

# or list of dicts
data = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':3}, {'a':10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30}]
```

if you are getting scalar error

do this

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'student1': 45, 'student2': 78, 'student3': 12, 'student4': 14, 'student5': 48, 'student6': 43, 'student7': 47, 'student8': 98, 'student9': 35, 'student10': 80}
for i in data.keys():
    data[i] = [data[i]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
df = DataFrame(list(my_dict.items()),columns = ['column1','column2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.DataFrame(dict_.items())
```

```
pd.DataFrame(dict_.items(), columns=['Student', 'Point'])
```

```
pd.Series(dict_, name='StudentValue')
```

All will work.